# LISP программа.Где ошибка в коде?

Tags: lisp, gnu

ОС: Windows 7, LISP: Common LISP 2.6.7. 
Пытаюсь выполнить вот этот код: `(defun summa-digits (n)
    (if (eq n 0) 0
    (+ (rem n 10) (summa-digits (truncate (/ n 10))))
    ))`

Получаю вот эту ошибку: [image: Ошибка]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Он же вам белым по черному пишет "Cannot open the file p1.lsp", в переводе на русский это значит "Не могу открыть файл p1.lsp".

Comment: Спасибо капитан.  Неужели трудно догадаться что вопрос в том, что почему не открывает его, ведь расширение соответствует

Comment: Я сегодня свой хрустальный шар дома забыл, неужели трудно догадаться.